# How to do TDD for Kendo UI used with ASP .Net MVC wrapper

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, tdd, kendo-ui

Is there any way or frameworks to writing unit tests for Javascripts used in ASP .NET MVC (View + Kendo UI) ? Or any Framework that supports mock data (from .net server e.g. controller) and then write unit tests for Javascripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chutzpah](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/) is a unit testing framework for Javascript. It also [integrates into the Visual Studio 2012 Test Runner](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71a4e9bd-f660-448f-bd92-f5a65d39b7f0) so that you can run these tests from Visual Studio or from TFS' Team Build.

Since Javascript allows you to redefine any function or method at runtime, I don't really see the need for a specific Mocking framework. You can mock anything in Javascript by default and almost without exception. You could also put any javascript functions that call into backend services into a separate .js file and just include a different one into the pages you are testing.